# call stack function prologue confusion

Tags: c, function, assembly, x86, callstack

I am trying to understand the function prologue of the call stack. As far as I know, it should start off like this:

```
push %rbp
movl %rsp, %rbp
...
```

yet I get

```
push   %rbp
mov    %rsp,%rbp
```

when I disassemble the main function of a basic printf program. My question is why is the address of the base pointer moved to the adress of the stack pointer and not the other way round like it is described in numerous (informative) youtube videos.
Thanks!

Comment: you have twice the same assembly code... But anyway I guess it's because your assembly samples are in ATT syntax and the samples you saw (which ones BTW?) probably use intel syntax where the operands are the other way round: Intel: `mov rbp, rsp`, ATT : `mov %rsp, %rbp`. Google _att vs intel syntax_

Comment: movl is a 32-bit move, but rsp and rbp are 64-bit registers, so you can’t use movl. You can use movq or just mov. With mov, the assembler determines the size from the operands.

Comment: the upper code snippet is the one I found in a youtube video. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: The `push` merely pushes the value in that register onto the stack so the register can be restored after it is used: the register is temporarily repurposed by that function and restored on its exit.  The `mov` simply copies the value of one register into the other.  To say address of base pointer moved to address of stack pointer or vice versa is overly complex, and somewhat implies memory store operation, which is not the case here.